# NSSearchField Category Menu State

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nssearchfield

I have an NSSearchField control where I want to show a few categories that are to appear as a menu when the user clicks on the arrow to the left.  After reading Apple's documentation, I have gotten some idea.  The following is my code.

```
// .h
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSSearchField  *searchField;
}

// .m
- (void)awakeFromNib {    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidBecomeKey:) name:NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object:[self window]];
    [window setContentBorderThickness:22.0 forEdge:NSMinYEdge];

    NSMenu *cellMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Search Menu",@"Search Menu title")];
    NSMenuItem *item;
    item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" action:@selector(setSearchCategoryFrom:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [item setTarget:self];
    [item setTag:1];
    [cellMenu insertItem:item atIndex:0];

    item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Username" action:@selector(setSearchCategoryFrom:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [item setTarget:self];
    [item setTag:2];
    [cellMenu insertItem:item atIndex:1];
    id searchCell = [searchField cell];
    [searchCell setSearchMenuTemplate:cellMenu];
}

- (IBAction)setSearchCategoryFrom:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem {
    if ([menuItem tag] == 0) {

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

And the screenshot below shows the result.  Now, I need to set the state of selection, whichever they choose, to 1 so that a checkmark will appear.  How do I do that?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work.

```
// .h
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSSearchField  *searchField;
    NSMenu *searchMenu;
}

// .m
@implementation AppDelegate {
    NSInteger lastSearchSelection;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {            
    NSMenu *cellMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Search Menu",@"Search Menu title")];
    NSMenuItem *item;
    item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" action:@selector(setSearchCategoryFrom:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [item setTarget:self];
    [item setTag:1];
    [cellMenu insertItem:item atIndex:0];

    item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Username" action:@selector(setSearchCategoryFrom:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [item setTarget:self];
    [item setTag:2];
    [cellMenu insertItem:item atIndex:1];
    id searchCell = [searchField cell];
    [searchCell setSearchMenuTemplate:cellMenu];
}

- (IBAction)setSearchCategoryFrom:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem {
    [[[sender menu] itemWithTag:lastSearchSelection] setState:NSOffState];
    [sender setState: NSOnState];
    lastSearchSelection = [sender tag];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would to add a categories menu (ex: search for Subject, Body or ...)
 in my NSSearchField. I've successfully set the menu but there is a
 problem if I try to set a menuitem to state:NSOffState.
 When I select a menu it should be to turn off the previous selected
 category. This is the code:

```
- (IBAction) menu_selectNewFilter:(id) sender {

NSMenuItem *m = [searchMenu itemWithTag: selectedFilter];
[m setState: NSOffState];
NSLog(@"Disabled %@ %d",[m title],[m tag]);

NSLog(@"Activate %@ %d",[sender title],[sender tag]);
[sender setState: NSOnState];

selectedFilter = [sender tag];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)setSearchCategoryFrom:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem {
    [[[sender menu] itemWithTag:lastSearchSelection] setState:NSOffState];
    [sender setState: NSOnState];
    lastSearchSelection = [sender tag];
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't even know what searchMenu and selectedFilter are, though.

Comment: http://blog.jameskyle.org/2010/10/toggling-nsmenuitems-for-a-nssearchfield-menu-template/ you can refer this

Comment: Whew...  I've got it.